# BeginGetRequestStream takes a long time to receive the response

Tags: c#, android

I am trying to connect between Android device and a Windows device. When I send BeginGetRequestStream to Android device it receives the callback response after a long time, around 1500 millisecond and rarely less than 500 . Can some one give me any tip for this

Comment: Perhaps it takes that long for the response to come back? Have you looked at what the network traffic is like, e.g. with Wireshark?

Comment: Where does Apache come into this?

Comment: I tried installing WireShark , It says Error opening file for writing. I tried to skip that and all the files gives the same error. I tried reinstalling . It gave the same error again. Please help